# IE 10 CSS Hyperlink Styles

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I am working on a project to convert an IE6 app to IE10 / Standards compliants browsers.

The project has hyperlinks which are rendered as images using css

```
<a href="somelink.htm" class="Icon_Page">

.Icon_Page
{
    background-image: url('../images/icons/page.png') ; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding:0px 16px 0px 0px;
}
```

The icons are 16 pixels squared. I have updated the CSS  to the below and they render more or less correctly in Chrome and Safari now. In IE 9/10 in standards mode the images are not rendered. What does the css need to show in order to render out the image in IE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should assign height and width to a tag css and may be set `display: block;`

Comment: OK; updated my CSS to .Icon_PageAdd 
{
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    display: block;    
   background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  background-image: url('../images/icons/page_add.png') ; 
  background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding:0px 16px 0px 0px;
} but it is still not showing the icon in IE.

Comment: no it's jst for my convenience only , so that I can understand that what you tryid exactly

Comment: Ohh!! i missed one this you didn't closed your '</a> :)'

check this http://jsfiddle.net/hPXvf/1/ and still you suffering then please check your Image URL/path is correct or not

Comment: Hi; Created the sample phttp://jsfiddle.net/gMZA3/ then saw your example code. The missing close tag is a transcription error. Your example CSS appears to work in the jsfiddle site so am giving it a go in the application. Thanks